# Query excel spreadsheet for cell format.... (percentage)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ado.net

I am using the .Net 4.0 and excel 2003

How can i use an oledb connection to retrieve the cell format of an excel spreadsheet... I specifically want to find out if a cell column (or cell itself) is in a numeric percentage format.

I cannot seem to find this information in the GetOleDbSchemaTable method.

EX: My web app reads numbers from an excel spreadsheet. This works fine; However, if the numbers are in a percentage format, excel displays it as (fraction*100) but the actual value is a fractional decimal (1/3 = .3333..) - Excel displays as 33.33% - (Notice the decimal point).

Therefore, i need a way of distinguishing between what is a percentage & what is not to allow my webapp to work properly...

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get out this information with `OleDbConnection.GetSchema`, but I'm not sure what information you'll get for an Excel sheet with that. Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135981.aspx).

Comment: @Guyanese4life: Well, it's fairly sparse, but it tells you that if you call that method you'll get out a DataTable with some data, that data might contain the info you need (it would if connected to a database but I've never tried it while connected to Excel).

Comment: @Guyanese4life: Here's another link discussing how to use it against Excel: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/31/2975.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Search the NumberFormat property of the Cell (Range) in question for a % sign.

Also, if you can get the format type, then you're looking for a format that starts with 'P', like 'P1'.

**EDIT:**  The only way I can see is either using XML or Automation.  For automation you need to use the Interop Assembly.  **Namespace:** Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, **Interface:** DisplayFormat, **Property:** [NumberFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.displayformat.numberformat.aspx).

Comment: There are no number format properties.. Keep in mind that this is being done by an oledb query.. I am NOT openning an instance of excel.

Comment: @Guy, I think they're gettable, but you may have to use a different function.  I've also edited in another way, but I also don't have the details on how to get that value.  I'll try to do some research when I can, because I'm all curious now on how to get this done.  Please update if you find the answer.

Comment: @Guy, ok, more info.  I realize that it's still not a complete answer, but hopefully it may lead you closer.

Answer (score -1):

Can you just read the first row of data as a string and parse it looking for '%' in the string.

Comment: -1 judging from the op's question the cell value doesn't contain %. The % is formatting applied by Excel specified in cell formatting.

Comment: Correct! This seems true. The table schema information says that the datatype of the specified column is "5", which correlates to a double or float (http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp); It does not give the excel cell(or column) format - which is a percentage

Comment: Well that sucks.  When you export an Excel worksheet to csv, the % sign comes with it.  Actually what gets saved is exactly what you see on the screen, even down to the number if decimal places.